# Mode function for Filtered data in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
mode_rate = WorksheetFunction.Mode(Sheets("RVW Data").Range("AL2:AL9000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
Sheets("Template").Range("L1") = mode_rate
End Sub
```

I have used the above code for calculating the mode of a *filtered data*, but its not working.

Please any one help

Comment: If you have Excel 2010 or later, use the `AGGREGATE` worksheet function instead, which has a Mode function and will ignore filtered rows.

Comment: Is the problem fixed?

Comment: Yeah, Temporarily I am using the code which you have given below. But I need the code without creating the "Temp" Sheet

Comment: I don't now how to do it without a temp sheet rigth now. you could do use a loop where you split the Range after every Row that's hidden. Why do you need a solution without creating a temp sheet?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you have is Because of the Range Object.
If you don't have filtered the Data the address of the range that you given the **.Mode Function** looks like

[image]
*Nice and Clean*

but if you filter the Data and some rows are hidden, the address of the range will look like this:

[image]
*chaos*

And the mode functions will throug an Error because he can't handel the Values Proper.
You have to add  Temp Sheet where you can copy only the Visible Rows and then use this data for the mode Functions.

You can see how i did it, in the Code below.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("RVW Data")


    Application.Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Temp"
    Set wsTemp = ActiveSheet

    ws.Range("AL2:AL9000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=wsTemp.Range("A1")   

    Set rng = wsTemp.Columns(1) 

    mode_rate = WorksheetFunction.Mode(wsTemp.Range("A1:A9000"))
    Sheets("Template").Range("L1") = mode_rate    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True    
    End Sub
```